# Generate a link_to on the fly if a URL is found inside the contents of a db text field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an automated report tool (corp intranet) where the admins have a few text area boxes to enter some text for different parts of the email body.

What I'd like to do is parse the contents of the text area and wrap any hyperlinks found with link tags (so when the report goes out there are links instead of text urls).

Is ther a simple way to do something like this without figuring out a way of parsing the text to add link tags around a found (['http:','https:','ftp:] TO the first SPACE after)?

Thank You!
Ruby 1.87, Rails 2.3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a helper :

```
def make_urls(text)
  urls = %r{(?:https?|ftp|mailto)://\S+}i
  html_text = text.gsub urls, '<a href="\0">\0</a>'
  html_text
end
```

on the view just call this function , you will get the expected output.
like :

```
irb(main):001:0> string = 'here is a link: http://google.com'
=> "here is a link: http://google.com"
irb(main):002:0> urls = %r{(?:https?|ftp|mailto)://\S+}i
=> /(?:https?|ftp|mailto):\/\/\S+/i
irb(main):003:0> html = string.gsub urls, '<a href="\0">\0</a>'
=> "here is a link: <a href=\"http://google.com\">http://google.com</a>"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to accomplish your goal. One way would be to use Regex. If you have never heard of regex, this [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) should bring you up to speed.

For example:

```
content_string = "Blah ablal blabla lbal blah blaha http://www.google.com/ adsf dasd dadf dfasdf dadf sdfasdf dadf dfaksjdf kjdfasdf http://www.apple.com/ blah blah blah."
content_string.split(/\s+/).find_all { |u| u =~ /^https?:/ }
```

Which will return: `["http://www.google.com/", "http://www.apple.com/"]`

Now, for the second half of the problem, you will use the array returned above to subsititue the text links for hyperlinks.

```
links = ["http://www.google.com/", "http://www.apple.com/"]
links.each do |l|
  content_string.gsub!(l, "<a href='#{l}'>#{l}</a>")
end
```

`content_string` will now be updated to contain HTML hyperlinks for all http/https URLs.

As I mentioned earlier, there are numerous ways to tackle this problem - to find the URLs you could also do something like:

```
require 'uri'
URI.extract(content_string, ['http', 'https'])
```

I hope this helps you.